# Why `heapq.merge(some_lists_of_iterators)` does not return an iterator of iterators?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator, heap, generator

In the following code:

```
import heapq

nums = [1,2,3]
result = [set([])]
bases = []

for n in nums:
    bases.append(set([n]))       # Now bases is [set([1]), set([2]), set([3])]

def gen (base):
    for r in result:
        if base != r:
            yield base | r       # It yields set([]) unions base

itr1 = iter(map(gen, bases))
itr2 = heapq.merge(*map(gen, bases))
```

Why itr1 is an iterator of iterators, but itr2 is an iterator of sets? Like shown below:

```
for i in itr1:
    print i                      #<generator object gen at 0x1028adcd0> 
                                 #<generator object gen at 0x1028add20> 
                                 #<generator object gen at 0x1028d5730>

for i in itr2:
    print i,                     #set([3]) set([2]) set([1])
```

Comment: What were you expecting? Why are you using `heapq.merge` on unordered data? And note that the whole point of it is that it gives you the items from the things it's merging, not the things themselves.

Comment: In order for `heapq.merge` to sort the iterables, it needs to iterate over each. This would exhaust the originally supplied generators and there is no way to go back and recreate them. Thus, it makes sense that the output would be the items in the generators rather than the generators themselves.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Thanks for replying. I think `heapq.merge` is merging those generators?

Comment: Yes... [`heapq.merge`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) indeed merges all supplied iterables.

Comment: And how did you think it would do that? Were you expecting it to return single-element iterables?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing:

```
itr1 = iter(map(gen, bases))
itr2 = heapq.merge(*map(gen, bases))
```

to:

```
itr1 = iter(map(gen, bases))
itr2 = iter(heapq.merge(*map(gen, bases)))
```